# AdMob ad not showing after updating app version on App Store

Tags: ios, flutter, admob

I updated my app on Apple's App Store (from 1.0 to 1.1) and now my AdMob ads do not show anymore. Do I need to create a different ad unit for each version? App was developed in Flutter. Implementation should be fine since it was working before.

Also asked here, for reference: https://support.google.com/admob/thread/140273254/ads-do-not-show-after-update?hl=en

Comment: No there is no need to create new ad units for every update. Do you see anything in the logs? Is there a hold on your AdMob account (happens if your account is new)?

Comment: Try ask here https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk